# TypeScript + Vue: What return Type to use for an object that contains a reactive() and ref() variable?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue 3 composable function.

It returns an object that contains one `reactive()` variable and one `ref()` variable.

And I would like to set a return type on this function to satisfy an eslint error.

But I'm new to Vue and TypeScript and not sure what the return type should be.

- If I use `unknown` then TS throws an error `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)` when calling the function.
- If I use `any` eslint complains with another error because it doesn't like the `any` type
- If I use `object` eslint complains that I should use `<Record<string, unknown>` instead because `object` is currently hard to use
- If I use `<Record<string, unknown>` then I get a ton of errors on the function itself regarding unassignable types.

So what should I use as the `useCollection()` return type?

```
import { ref, reactive, watchEffect } from "vue";
import { projectFirestore } from "@/firebase/config";
import {
  query,
  orderBy,
  onSnapshot,
  DocumentData,
  collection,
} from "firebase/firestore";

const useCollection: any = (collectionPath: string) => { //<-- Need to replace this "any" with something else
  const documentsArray = reactive<Record<string, unknown>[]>([]);
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);
  // references
  const collectionReference = collection(projectFirestore, collectionPath);
  const collectionOrdered = query(
    collectionReference,
    orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  );
  // updates
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    collectionOrdered,
    (snapshot) => {
      documentsArray.splice(0);
      snapshot.forEach((doc: DocumentData) => {
        documentsArray.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
      });
      error.value = null;
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      documentsArray.splice(0);
      error.value = err.message;
    }
  );
  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    console.log("watchEffect fired");
    onInvalidate(() => {
      console.log("onInvalidate fired");
      unsubscribe();
    });
  });
  return { documentsArray, error };
};

export default useCollection;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reactive` returns the same object type as provided, with inner refs being unwrapped, which can be ignored depending on specified object.

`ref` returns `Ref` type.

For this function a type would be:

```
(collectionPath: string) => { documentsArray: Record<string, unknown>[] , error: Ref<string | null> }
```

There may be no need to specify the type for `useCollection` variable because it's inferred from the function. Return type is inferred from the single return value, `{ documentsArray, error }`, where both `documentsArray` and `error` are constants that have their types inferred on assignment either.

If a type needs to be more specific than inferred one, e.g. collection values are  known, this is handled by generics:

```
const useCollection = <T extends unknown = unknown>(collectionPath: string) => {
  const documentsArray = reactive<Record<string, T>[]>([]);
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);
  ...

const c = useCollection<string | number>(...);
```

Comment: Have awarded the bounty to this answer because it seems to work, but would you mind showing how `(collectionPath: string) => { documentsArray: Record<string, unknown>[] , error: Ref<string | null> }` fits within my code? I'm confused by why this `(collectionPath: string) =>` is needed as part of a function return Type. Seeing everything implemented as part of my entire code file provided in the question would help me understand more.

Comment: This is not just return type, this is the type for the whole function. It is meant to be `const useCollection: (collectionPath: string) => { documentsArray: ...} = (collectionPath: string) => {...}`. It's listed for reference only. It doesn't fit because useCollection type is inferred and doesn't need to be specified explicitly.

Comment: note: `reactive`'s signature is : `function reactive<T extends object>(target: T): UnwrapNestedRefs<T>`. You can search in the `reactivity.d.ts` file for more info

Answer (score -1):

Mine works with `any` but I guess it is because of your project rules like eslint or tsconfig.

You need to define your return type like this.

```
const useCollection: (collectionPath: string) : { documentsArray: reactive<Record<string, unknown>[]>; error: ref<string | null>; } => { 
     // write your code
}
```

Or you can use by defining interface.

```
interface CollectionResult {
    documentsArray: reactive<Record<string, unknown>[]>;
    error: ref<string | null>;
}
const useCollection: (collectionPath: string) : CollectionResult => { 
    // write your code
}
```

Comment: ref and reactive are functions and not valid types